# Building zookeeper 3.4.12 c client on solaris machine fails with libtool error

Tags: shell, solaris, apache-zookeeper, libtool

I am trying to build zookeeper 3.4.12 c client on the Solaris machine. Below are the steps that I followed,

1. unzip/untar the source tarball and cd to the zookeeper-x.x.x/src/c
   directory.
2. Do a "./configure [OPTIONS]" to generate the makefile. 
        ./configure --without-cppunit

This step fails with below error,

```
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC    --mode=link gcc  -Wall -Werror -g -O2
-D_GNU_SOURCE -no-undefined -version-info 2 -lnsl -lsocket -export-symbols-regex '(zoo_|zookeeper_|zhandle|Z|format_log_message|log_message|logLevel|deallocate_|allocate_|zerror|is_unrecoverable)'
-o libzookeeper_st.la -rpath /usr/local/lib  libzkst.la libhashtable.la libtool: link: /bin/nm -p   ./.libs/libzkst.a ./.libs/libhashtable.a |  | /bin/gsed 's/.* //' | sort | uniq > .libs/libzookeeper_st.exp ./libtool[1732]: eval: syntax error at line 1: `|' unexpected
*** Error code 3 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `libzookeeper_st.la'
```

Any idea on the error?

Regards,
Ashwini.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're missing a command in this portion of the command line:

```
... ./.libs/libzkst.a ./.libs/libhashtable.a |  | /bin/gsed 's/.* //' ...
```

If you can find that recipe in the Makefile, there's probably a $(something) there that's expanded to an empty string, thus attempting a null command in the pipeline.

Comment: I tried alot to find out. But couldnot get any clues. I am trying to attach make file copy here. How can I attach a file to this thread?

Comment: Found the issue. There was something like this in make file : "libzookeeper_st.la: $(libzookeeper_st_la_OBJECTS) $(libzookeeper_st_la_DEPENDENCIES) 
 $(AM_V_CCLD)$(libzookeeper_st_la_LINK) -rpath $(libdir)". Where in if I remove -rpath $(libdir) everything builds properly. Dont know what -rpath $(libdir) does.  -rpath $(libdir) expands to  "-rpath /usr/local/lib"

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. There was something like this in make file :

"libzookeeper_st.la: $(libzookeeper_st_la_OBJECTS) $(libzookeeper_st_la_DEPENDENCIES) $(AM_V_CCLD)$(libzookeeper_st_la_LINK) -rpath $(libdir)".

Where in if I remove **-rpath $(libdir)** everything builds properly. 
Dont know what -rpath $(libdir) does. -rpath $(libdir) expands to "-rpath /usr/local/lib". But this resolves the issue.